# Update specific cells

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview

So i have a tableview which is showing json data.

first from `JSON1 = [{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac"}]`
and details of each cell fetched from the second json.

`JSON2 = [{"serverid":98,"updated": "10:29 PM"},{"serverid":65,"updated": "10:29 PM"}]`

now After 60 second i again make a call to servers to get just `JSON 2` back (order in which i get my json is random).

there is a parameter last updated. Based on that i will check which cell to update.

But how do I update only selected cells?
(not complete tableview but specific cell)

I know the fucntion `"reloadRows(at: [indexPath]"` but i don't how to pass selected cell to this function?

Comment: I think you need to get JSON2 in JSON1 like this **`[{"serverid":65,"name":"Apple","updated": "10:29 PM"},{"serverid":98,"name":"Mac","updated": "10:29 PM"}]`** Because JSON1 and JSON2 are unorders. If you want to do same as above that you mentioned then you need to sort data based on "serverid".

Comment: //Update specific row (these two lines of code)
 let indexPath = IndexPath(item: rowNumber, section: 0)//Here you need to mention your updated row's
 self.uploadDocumentsTableView.reloadRows(at: [indexPath], with: .top)

Comment: @iOS, don't you think the "updated" value goes wrong here. because if i load data in `tableView` from JSON1 then first row contain `Apple` and if i update it with JSON2 then `Mac` "updated" value set to `Apple`.

Answer (score 0):

When you say selected, that implies the cell has `isSelected == true`. If that is the case, then you could use `indexPathsForSelectedRows`

```
if let indexPaths = tableView.indexPathsForSelectedRows {
    tableView.reloadRows(at: indexPaths, with: .automatic)
}
```

---

However, if by selected you mean rows in your data source that need to be changed by the 60 second update, then you need to provide more details. How are you binding the data source to cells `tableView(_:cellForRowAt:)`.